# Can't set properly TableViewCell's Row Height

Tags: ios

I am trying to complete a tutorial about iOS8 SDK Development. When i try to create a custom cell, I am getting a result like that with cell's height:

I have a table view like that:
[image: TableView]

I setted Row Height for this cell:

[image: Row Height]

But i am getting result like that:
[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your storyboard, select the `UITableView` and open the attributes panel and set the Row Height here too.

[image]

Setting the TableCell height **only** doesn't change the height as the compiler will also take height data from the UITableView, hence change it here too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have implemented the delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath since it mutual exclusive with the value u set on the designer

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return height;
}
```